# How to add a custom year drop-down in place of Export CSV drop-down on admin panel for custom grid and filter the collection?

Tags: php, magento-1.7, admin, dropdown

I need to add a custom year drop-down in place of Export CSV drop-down, on admin panel for custom grid and filter the collection showing quarterly commission report.

[image]

Comment: Why don't you add a dropdown using html and form get method and basis of selection you modify your database query and generate result?

Comment: are you asking for design help or a php code ?

Comment: The design idea for the solution from me is: include date/time column to your gird, add mass action to your gird with ability to export it as CSV. There are a lot of samples inside Magento how to implement both. Than, when you want to export your grid, you can filter it by year and receive filtered data in generated CSV.